# Laravel Require if is null in database

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

laravel 5.8
I want a rule of laravel validation for update that be like this: 
only push error when the value of this field is null and this field in the database is null too

if the field is null but in the database this field has value that validation is ok

I tried this

```
            'logo' => 'required_without:logo',
```

Comment: Did you get an error? What happened? What version of Laravel are you using? Have you tried using `exists:table,column`?

Comment: @ThomasEdwards I want a rule of laravel for validation that is like required but that  let user submit data if that field in the database has value  , laravel 5.8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have to write a custom [Rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#custom-validation-rules) or do some checks on the field to wrap around your validation definitions.

```php
$rules= [...];

if($model->field === null){
    $rules['logo' => 'required'];
}
```

Comment: laravel dont have a ready rule for this ? , change !== to ===

Comment: Brilliant work around.